# Webstorm 2018 override type

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, webstorm

I'm using Webstorm 2018.3 on Ubuntu 18.04. When I type every char is always overridden,

[image: see this GIF]

Please, someone can help me?

Comment: Have you tried pressing the insert key?

Comment: Yes, I tried. Nothing changed

Comment: can be a broken installation. Please upload your idea.log file (**Help | Show log in <your file manager>**) to some file server and provide a link here

Comment: Sure!! You can find log [here](https://we.tl/t-BcMJheaR0c)